# R: how to get names of list of lists in original order?

Tags: r, list

I want to get the names of a list of lists. Therefore I want to paste (or add) the names of the list elements (first levels) with the names of the list of lists elements (2nd levels). This should be done with a ".". Important for me is to have the names in the same order as in the list of lists. Here an example (notice that I have far more sublists as this nine per element) without values:

```
GER_WF_groups <- list(A=list(fruits.2000=matrix(),nuts.2000=matrix(),veggies.2000=matrix(),
            fruits.2001=matrix(),nuts.2001=matrix(),veggies.2001=matrix(),
            fruits.2002=matrix(),nuts.2002=matrix(),veggies.2002=matrix()), 
     B=list(fruits.2000=matrix(),nuts.2000=matrix(),veggies.2000=matrix(),
            fruits.2001=matrix(),nuts.2001=matrix(),veggies.2001=matrix(),
            fruits.2002=matrix(),nuts.2002=matrix(),veggies.2002=matrix()), 
     C=list(fruits.2000=matrix(),nuts.2000=matrix(),veggies.2000=matrix(),
            fruits.2001=matrix(),nuts.2001=matrix(),veggies.2001=matrix(),
            fruits.2002=matrix(),nuts.2002=matrix(),veggies.2002=matrix()))
```

Until know I use a complicated way to get to this ordered names, but it works, see below:

```
years_sapply2 <- sapply(GER_WF_groups,function(x) paste("BLUE", names(x) ,sep="."))
str(years_sapply2)
years_mat2 <- matrix(years_sapply2, nrow=9, byrow=F)
years_mat3 <- matrix(years_mat2, ncol=1, byrow=F)
years_vec <- years_mat3[,1]
BLUEyears <- years_vec[1:9]
GREENyears <- BLUEyears
GREYyears <- BLUEyears
GREENyearsN <- sub("BLUE", "GREEN", GREENyears)
GREYyearsN <- sub("BLUE", "GREY", GREYyears)
years_namesALL <- c(BLUEyears, GREENyearsN, GREYyearsN)
```

My question is: Is there a faster/easier way to do this job? Thanks

"years_namesALL" is the expected result.

Comment: How deeply nested are your lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Vongo's approach would be something like the following:

```
names(unlist(setNames(GER_WF_groups, c("BLUE", "GREEN", "GREY"))))
##  [1] "BLUE.fruits.2000"   "BLUE.nuts.2000"     "BLUE.veggies.2000" 
##  [4] "BLUE.fruits.2001"   "BLUE.nuts.2001"     "BLUE.veggies.2001" 
##  [7] "BLUE.fruits.2002"   "BLUE.nuts.2002"     "BLUE.veggies.2002" 
## [10] "GREEN.fruits.2000"  "GREEN.nuts.2000"    "GREEN.veggies.2000"
## [13] "GREEN.fruits.2001"  "GREEN.nuts.2001"    "GREEN.veggies.2001"
## [16] "GREEN.fruits.2002"  "GREEN.nuts.2002"    "GREEN.veggies.2002"
## [19] "GREY.fruits.2000"   "GREY.nuts.2000"     "GREY.veggies.2000" 
## [22] "GREY.fruits.2001"   "GREY.nuts.2001"     "GREY.veggies.2001" 
## [25] "GREY.fruits.2002"   "GREY.nuts.2002"     "GREY.veggies.2002"
```

If you only have one level of nesting, you can try:

```
names(unlist(setNames(GER_WF_groups, c("BLUE", "GREEN", "GREY")), recursive = FALSE))
```

Comment: Indeed, this is better.

Comment: Was about to post the same. I'd just add `recursive=FALSE` in `unlist` to handle cases in which element of the list are not of length 1.

Comment: On this example works fine. However, in my original list I have matrices of 250x250 with names. And I get all this names too, so I get for example "BLUE.fruits.2012.Germany" and so on. Is there a wat to put the matrices colnames out of. Is the same problem with @Vongos answer

Comment: @nicola, It appears that your approach was required.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this :

```
gsub("C","GREY",gsub("A","BLUE",gsub("B","GREEN",names(unlist(GER_WF_groups)))))
```

**EDIT** (shamelessly copied on @Ananda Mahto's edit on the same issue) :

```
gsub("C","GREY",gsub("A","BLUE",gsub("B","GREEN",names(unlist(GER_WF_groups,recursive=F)))))
```

But the nested `gsub` is clearly not elegant.

Comment: see my comment on @Ananda Mahto's answer